# Android Application's onCreate called mutiple times, How to guarantee only run initialize res one time

Tags: android

I am going to run some initialize code for my app, but there are two process, one is my main process, another is keep active process. now Application OnCreate() will run two times, i just want to run one time initialize code in my main process. I know there is a way, I can ActivityManager get running process information , By comparing the pid know current process information, like below code:

```
public static String getProcessNameByPID(Context context, int pid){
        ActivityManager manager
                = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

        for(ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : manager.getRunningAppProcesses()){
            if(processInfo.pid == pid){
                return processInfo.processName;
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

but now Android 5.0+ killed getRunningTasks(int) and    getRunningAppProcesses(), Are there any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just check if a global variable was declared.

```
private String globalString;
private int globalInt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (globalString == nil)
    {
        globalString = "Declaration";
        globalInt = 42;
        //Everything else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean firstTime= true;

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     if (firstTime) {
         //Code to run first time
   }
}
```

I used to run code first time.

Comment: it's not useful, because two process don't use same firstTime variate.